# MVC5 Form Post null item prevention

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, form-submit, model-binding

I am fairly new to MVC (my experience is of about 4 months). I am trying to build a mini-CMS that modifies existing Articles and creates new ones stored in MongoDB.

In order the maintain the "schema" of my MongoDB constant accross documents and preventing type mismatches, and since some of my Model fields are not required, I want to ask if what I am doing to prevent null entries is correct.

In my Article Model I do the following:

- for integer, bool, and DateTime entries:

  ```
  public class Article {
  private int? _id;

  [BsonRequired]
  [BsonElement("_id")]
  public int? Id
  {
      get { return _id ?? 0; }
      set { _id = value; }
  }
  ...
  private DateTime? _dateLastPublished;

  [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
  [BsonElement("date_last_published")]
  public DateTime? DateLastPublished
  {
      get { return _dateLastPublished ?? new DateTime(); }
      set { _dateLastPublished = value; }
  }
  ...
  private bool? _main;

  [BsonElement("isMain")]
  public bool? Main
  {
      get { return _main ?? false; }
      set { _main = value; }
  }
  }
  ```

  - For string properties, I add the addribute `[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]`
  - For `List<T>`:

    ```
    private List<string> _tags;
    [BsonElement("tags")]
    public List<string> Tags {
    get { return _tags ?? new List<string>(); }
    set { _tags = value; } }
    ```

Is this the correct logic? Or am I doing this completely wrong? As far as the outcome is concerned, it is correct. I just want to know I am not picking up any bad habits by doing this.

Any insight is extremely appreciated. Thank you very much for your time.